# Using a one dimensional array to calculate a matrix value

Tags: c, arrays, loops

The problem is:

Given non-negative integers m and n compute A(m,n) iteratively given that:

```
A(m,n) = A(m, n-1) + A(m-1, n), m, n >= 0
A(m,n) = m - n, if m < 0 or n < 0
```

The first part of the question uses a 2 Dimensional array (of m+1 times n+1 size) to fill an array and the position at (m,n) contains the value.  This was the easy part.

The second part, however states:

devise an algorithm to do this this using only a 1-dmensional array of size min{m; n} + 1 only. Implement a C program for such an algorithm.

My thoughts: To calculate the first row and column I am using the following function.

```
int Firsts(int x, int y)
{
    int total, order;

    if (x == 0)
    {
        if (y % 2 == 1)
        {
            order = (y/2) + 2;
            total = y * order;
        }
        else
        {
            total = (y * ((y/2) + 1)) + (y/2);
        }
        return -total;
    }
    else
    {
        if (x % 2 == 1)
        {
            order = (x/2) + 2;
            total = x * order;
        }
        else
        {
            total = (x * ((x/2) + 1)) + (x/2);
        }

        return total;
    }
}
```

Now I need to move down and to the right (using the one above it and one to the left).  However, I am at a loss as to how to do this iteratively.  I used a min function to initialize the array size but that is what I have so far.

Comment: A hint for you : use [Pascal's Triangle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal's_triangle)

Answer (score 0):

You should "trace" the 2D program by doing the algorithm by hand, on paper. If you don't know what is happening, or can't do it by hand, you are in no position to make changes to the algorithm.

Once you have done it by hand, probably at least a couple of times with different numbers, you  should be able to observe that you only need some of the "old" (previous) numbers in order to find the new values. Most likely you will discover that you only need some of the previous row and/or some of the current row (this is because of the `-1`'s). Once you understand what is happening you can code it up.

Answer (score 0):

This is a serious issue, I spent few hours thinking about it :)

I will use your `Firsts` as it is and add the following :

```
int fact(int a)
{
    if(a == 0) return 1;
    return(a*fact(a-1));
}

int Combi(int n, int k)
{
    return(fact(n)/(fact(k)*fact(n-k)));
}

int main()
{
  int size, ii, m, n, value, plus;
  m = 5;
  n = 3;
  size = m>n ? m:n;

  int* array;
  array = malloc(size*sizeof(int));

  for(ii = 0; ii<= size; ii++)
  {
      array[ii] = Firsts(ii, 0); // fill my 1D array
  }

  value = 0;  // initialization
  if(m==0) value= array[n];
  else if(n==0) value = array[m];

  else
  {
    for(ii = 0; ii <= m; ii ++)
    {
        plus = Combi(n+ii-1, ii) * array[m-ii] * 1;
        value += plus;
    }
    for(ii = 0; ii <= n; ii ++)
    {
        plus = Combi(m+ii-1, ii) * array[n-ii]* (-1);
        value += plus;
    }
  }
  printf("A[%d, %d] = %d\n", m, n, value);

}
```

It's quite hard to understand, I will leave it to you for the moment to try understand the code, if you make it or you gave up notify me ;)

**NOTE**
I guess it was a typo but the size of 1D array is MAX(m, n)